# How are JavaScript arrays represented in physical memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, weakly-typed

It is my understanding that I can store mixed data in a JavaScript array, as well as change any element in the array to some other type. How does the interpreter keep track of what place in physical memory any element is at. Also how is the overwriting of the data in the next element prevented if I change an element to a larger data type.

I assume that arrays only store references to actual objects, and primitives are wrapped behind the scenes when placed in arrays.

Assuming this is the case, If I have a different handle on the primitive variable and change the value stored in the array is synchronicity maintained?

I know I probably already answered my own question, but I don't know for sure and I can't find any information on the matter.

Comment: Different implementations of JavaScript may have different methods for this.

Comment: You can't modify primitives. Assigning an array element will never change some other variable or array. (If the array is an element of another array (or multiple other arrays), the change will be visible through the other array(s), but you'll never, say, have `x=3`, assign to an array somewhere, and then suddenly see that `x==4`.)

Comment: is this what you mean  http://jsfiddle.net/2xBdx/1

Comment: Arrays in JS are unlike arrays in other languages. They don't have those optimizations that come from having a contiguous section of memory and one simple multiply-operation to get the desired memory address for item i. In JS Arrays are really objects - hashes, and if the particular JS implementation has an optimization, and what kind, depends. Worst case is the indexes are just hash keys, so the second array item at index 1 is located using hash key "1" in the object. Advantage: sparse arrays (huge with very few actual values). Disadvantage: most (small) arrays (unless internally optimized).

Comment: @Brad's simple comment should be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Normally, arrays allocate a contiguous block of memory of fixed length. However, in Javascript, arrays are Object types with special constructors and accessor methods.

Which means, a statement like:

```
var arr = new Array(100000);
```

does not allocate any memory! In fact, it simply sets the value of the length property in the array. When you construct an array, you don't need to declare a size as they grow automatically. So, you should use this instead:

```
var arr = [];
```

Arrays in Javascript are sparse which means not all the elements in the array may contain data. In other words, only the elements that actually contain data exist in the array. This reduces the amount of memory used by the array. The values are located by a key and not by an offset. They're simply a method of convenience and not intended to be used for complex numerical analysis.

Arrays in Javascript are not typed so the value of an element can be an object, string, number, boolean, function or an array. The main difference between an array and an object is the length property which has a value greater than the largest integer key in the array.

**For example:**

You could have an create an empty array and add two elements at index 0 and index 99. The length would be 100, but the number of elements in the array would be 2.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[99] = {name: "John"};
console.log(arr.length); // prints 100
arr; // prints something like [0, undefined × 98, Object { name: "John"}]
```

**To answer your questions directly:**

> Q. It is my understanding that I can store mixed data in a JavaScript array, as well as change any element in the array to some other type. How does the interpreter keep track of what place in physical memory any element is at? Also, how is the overwriting of the data in the next element prevented if I change an element to a larger data type?
>
> A. You probably know this by now if you've read my comments above. In Javascript, an array is a Hashtable Object type so the interpreter doesn't need to keep track of physical memory and changing the value of an element doesn't affect other elements as they're not stored in a contiguous block of memory.

--

> Q. I assume that arrays only store references to actual objects, and primitives are wrapped behind the scenes when placed in arrays. Assuming this is the case, if I have a different handle on the primitive variable and change the value stored in the array is synchronicity maintained?
>
> A. No, primitives are not wrapped. Changing a primitive that was assigned to an array will not change the value in the array as they're stored by value. Objects on the other hand are stored by reference, so changing the objects value will reflect that change in that array.

**Here's an example you can try:**

```
var arr = [];
var obj = { name: "John" };
var isBool = true;

arr.push(obj);
arr[1] = isBool;

console.log(arr[0]); // print obj.name
console.log(arr[1]); // print true

obj.age = 40;        // add age to obj
isBool = false;      // change value for isBool

console.log(arr[0]); // value here will contain age
console.log(arr[1]); // value here will still be true
```

Also, note that when you initialize an array in the following two ways, it has a different behavior:

```
var arr = new Array(100);
console.log(arr.length);        // prints 100
console.log(arr);               // prints []

var arr2 = new Array(100, 200);
console.log(arr2.length);       // prints 2
console.log(arr2);              // prints [100, 200]
```

If you want to use Javascript Arrays as contiguous blocks of memory, you should look into using [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). TypedArray's allow you to allocate a block of memory as a byte array and access the raw binary data more efficiently.

You can learn more about the intricacies of Javascript by reading the [ECMA-262 spec (ver 5.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf).

Comment: Great answer, but I think it's worthwhile to note that there's a lot of hand-waving going on here about things that are implementation-defined. For example, in SpiderMonkey (the backbone of early Mozilla JS implementations), arrays are implemented as dense C arrays of jsvals until you do certain operations on them, at which point the engine can switch them to objects underneath you.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for bringing that up. I was just thinking about that and wanted to edit the answer, but probably in the AM.

Comment: This jsperf seems to contradict the idea that pre-allocating arrays in JS is not possible/beneficial: https://jsperf.com/array-allocation-push-vs-new-array-size-assignment

Comment: does this mean that arrays in javascript do not have cache locality ?

Comment: This is great. If anyone knows how to work with a TypedArray as external memory with V8 please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

Here is some food for thought. I made [a jsperf to test a simple array optimization](http://jsperf.com/array-optimization) that some JavaScript engines implement.

The test case creates two arrays with a million elements each. The `a` array contains only numbers; the `b` array contains the same numbers except for the first element which is an object:

```
var a = [ 0 ], b = [ { valueOf: function() { return 0; } } ];
for( var i = 1;  i < 1000000;  ++i ) {
    a[i] = b[i] = i;
}
```

The `valueOf` property of the object in the first element of the `b` array returns `0` so the arithmetic will be the same as the first array.

Then the two tests simply sum all the values for the two arrays.

Fast array:

```
var x = 0;
for( var i = 0;  i < 1000000;  ++i ) {
    x += a[i];
}
```

Slow array:

```
var x = 0;
for( var i = 0;  i < 1000000;  ++i ) {
    x += b[i];
}
```

As you can see from the test results in the jsperf, in Chrome the numeric array is about 5x faster, in Firefox the numeric array is about 10x faster, and in IE it's about 2x faster.

This doesn't directly reveal the internal structures used for the array, but it gives a pretty good indication that the two are quite different from each other.

Comment: are you kidding me? the slow array add an object with a number for 1000000 times! that's the difference! you should set var i = 1 in the jsperf loop

Comment: @yangguang1029 no, it does not. It once casts the object to a number on the first addition.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer says that

> [An array construction] does not allocate any memory!

Thats not necessarily true. Storing arrays as unordered key-value pairs as in objects, is very inefficient as every lookup is a search. Even if the entries were sorted, it would still allocate more memory than needed. Therefore a lot of engines represent arrays in a few different ways to safe memory and optimize performance. That can also be seen in Michael Geary's example, the array that ony contains numbers gets optimized ([details for V8](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds)). And sometimes the engine might decide to allocate some empty slots for a newly created array, if the underlying representation has a fixed size and can't be scaled that easily (e.g. an array list).

Answer (score 0):

When a value is assigned to a positive index outside the range of the array,
then the array stores this value at the specified index and all other indices
before it are empty. The length of the array also changes to 'index+1'.

When a negative value is used, then the array stores the element as a
key-value pair, where the negative index is the key and the element to be
inserted is the value.