# If an array has a set amount of memory, how can we "push" something into it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I just got to the Algorithm part of Javascript, and read that an array cannot grow. But how are we able to push items into an array? Is this "array" then copied and added additional block of memory?

Comment: I feel array in js is not fixed . It is dynamic ?

Comment: in JavaScript the Array object is actually not array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321047/how-are-javascript-arrays-represented-in-physical-memory

Answer (score 0):

An array that cannot grow is called a static array. JavaScript has dynamic arrays, which can be resized. They can grow. What book did you get this information from?