# ANGULAR 10 Does <empty slot> in array takes any memory

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an array in which I store elements fetched from database at the index position of their Id for convenience. Doing so, I can have a lot of  in my array, and now I wonder if these slots are actually stored in memory by angular (which would lead to changing my implementation) or not. I did some research but couldn't find an answer.
Example :
Fetch from DB : object{id=3, .....}, object{id=5, ....}
Array constructed : [<3 empty slot>, 3, <1 empty slot>, 5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't really have nothing to do with Angular, but with the language per-se, in this case, Typescript, which translates to Javascript.

That means your answer can be found in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321047/how-are-javascript-arrays-represented-in-physical-memory)

TL;DR:
No, those slots don't actually occupy memory