# Javascript array - actual structure of an array in memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose that there is a javascript array called fruitbox with length 10000.

**Guess1**

The actual structure of javascript array is literally linear.

(item delimiter item delimiter item delimiter ...)

It will generally take much more time, (about 1000 times more) to get fruitbox[5000] than fruitbox[5].

It is likely to find 5000th person/5th person in 10000 persons standing in line when your are standing at 1th person initially.

**Guess2**

The actual structure of javascript array uses indexing.

Given a natural number n, PC can get n-th element immediately.

It will generally take similar time to get fruitbox[5000] or fruitbox[5].

It is likely to find a word in 5000th page/5th page in 10000 page dictionary.

---

Which is true **Guess1** or **Guess2** ?

Comment: I have honestly thought about this question, just haven't posted it.

Comment: It’s the second one.

Comment: What do you mean by "literally linear"? Is this a question about traversal time or how the array looks in memory? if it's the later, [How are JavaScript arrays represented in physical memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321047/how-are-javascript-arrays-represented-in-physical-memory) points to Guess 2.

Comment: Thank you! It was about traversal time.There is no worry for creating large array.