# React is not re rendering after setState is called, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pages : [],
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(event){

    
   var newpages = this.state.pages;
   
    newpages.push(event);
    this.setState = ({
      pages: newpages,
    });
    console.log(this.state.pages)
    if(this.state.pages!=undefined)
    {this.state.pages.forEach(element => 
                            ((element!=undefined) ?console.log("jsjha"):console.log("hsdgahdhasgh") ))}
//working  
    
  }

  

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pages); // not working, nothing is printed in the console
    return (
      <>
    
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick("Tab 1")} value="Tab 1" id="1">Tab 1</button>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick("Tab 2")} value="Tab 2" id="2">Tab 2</button>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick("Tab 3")} value="Tab 3" id="3">Tab 3</button>
    <h3>Hello this is Data bar!</h3>
    <hr/>
    
    { 
      (this.state.pages.map(function(element,i)
        {return <p key={i}>{element}hdkashdak</p> }))
    }
// not working
                            
                   
    
    
    </>
    );
  }
}
```

In the console.log , I can see "jsjha" being printed, means the state is bein updated.
But in the render function I cannot see the set being updated.

I have even bind the handleClick function.

Also, is everything correct witht the JSX map function? I am using the return statement and still it isn't working.

Comment: `this.setState = ({ pages: newpages, });` - that's *assignment*, you're not calling the method.

Comment: The answer is in your own wording... *"after setState is **called**"*.  Nowhere in the code are you **calling** the `setState` function.

Comment: you have to change the value to rerender it, in your method you are setting the state value in the state again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the usage of this.setState is wrong. setState is a function you should call it not assign something to it. Besides this issue, there is another issue with array reference. Because you are using the previous array reference in the state, that is why react doesn't know if the array is changed or not. Thus not re-rendering. You have to make sure that the array reference for pages is changed by doing this,

```
this.setState({
  pages: [...newpages],
});
```

You can look into this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321047/how-are-javascript-arrays-represented-in-physical-memory) for more understanding

Comment: No need to Destructuring the newpages array.

Comment: The bigger issue is that `setState` is a function to be called, not a variable to be assigned, which you quietly corrected without mentioning.

Comment: My bad, @David, Thanks for mentioning. Updating my answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
export default class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pages : [],
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(event){
    this.setState({
      pages: [...this.state.pages, event],
    });
  }

  

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pages); // not working, nothing is printed in the console
    return (
      <>
    
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick("Tab 1")} value="Tab 1" id="1">Tab 1</button>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick("Tab 2")} value="Tab 2" id="2">Tab 2</button>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick("Tab 3")} value="Tab 3" id="3">Tab 3</button>
    <h3>Hello this is Data bar!</h3>
    <hr/>
    
    { 
      (this.state.pages.map(function(element,i)
        {return <p key={i}>{element}hdkashdak</p> }))
    }
// not working
                            
                   
    
    
    </>
    );
  }
}
```