# When and How Should I Use trackBy in Angular's ngFor Directive for Optimal Performance?

Tags: angular, performance, optimization, ngfor, angular-directive

I'm seeking clarification on the usage of the trackBy function with Angular's ngFor directive to enhance performance. While I understand the basics of ngFor and its iteration over arrays to generate templates, I'm uncertain about the specific scenarios and methodologies where trackBy should be employed.

Here's what I've attempted:

I've read the Angular documentation on trackBy, but I'm still unclear about its practical application.
I've experimented with ngFor loops in my Angular projects, but I'm uncertain about the necessity and proper implementation of trackBy.

I'm expecting a clear explanation of when and why it's beneficial to use trackBy in ngFor loops.
I'd like to understand any potential performance improvements or pitfalls associated with using or not using trackBy.
Examples or demonstrations illustrating effective usage of trackBy within ngFor loops would be highly beneficial.
Any guidance or insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

ngFor loops through array and generates a repeating template.

When something gets changed in the data object used to make the template, `ngFor` has two options.

1. Rerender the entire repeated elements
2. Rerender only the element, where the change occurred.

SO lets look at an example

```
array1 = [{test:1},{test:1}{test:1},{test:1}]; // this array is used for ngFor
    
    
//next an api call updates array1 //emulates an API call 
of([{test:1},{test:1}{test:1},{test:1}]).subscribe(() => {
    this.array1 = [{test:1},{test:1}{test:1},{test:1}];
});
```

So when you look at from `ngFor` perspective, it received an input array at the beginning, as you know javascript arrays are stored as references [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321047/how-are-javascript-arrays-represented-in-physical-memory) some reference to the location of the array in the memory.

When the API call is made, a new array is assigned to `array1`, but from the perspective of `ngFor` a new reference will be incoming, so naturally `ngFor` has to rerender the entire array because it does not know what changed inside the array.

When you specify `ngFor` with `trackBy` you specify the key with which to track the identify of the elements of the array, here is the id changes, we know something has happened to the elements and `differs` function of angular will catch the change and rerender.

For a more detailed look, try exploring the [`source code`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts)

Answer (score 0):

trackBy function is used with ngFor to improve the performance of rendering lists by providing a hint to Angular's change detection mechanism on how to track changes to the elements in the list.

If you're rendering a list with a large number of items, trackBy improve rendering performance.

If the data in your list can change dynamically, trackBy can help Angular to efficiently update the DOM without re-rendering all the items.

In your component.ts

```
  items: any[] = [{id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Item 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Item 3'}];

  trackById(index: number, item: any) {
    return item.id;
  }
```

In your component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackById">{{ item.name }}</li>
```