# Return last item first in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

I need a recursive function that returns the deepest item first because reversing array and pushing to first position are slow.

I have an object:

```
const myObject = {
    id: 3,
    parent: {
        id: 2,
        parent: {
            id: 1,
            parent: null,
        },
    },
};
```

And a recursive function:

```
function findParents(myObject, parents = []) {
  if (myObject.parent) {
    parents.push(myObject.parent.id);
    return findParents(myObject.parent, parents);
  }

  return parents; // [2, 1]
}
```

I need a recursive function that returns me an array of an objects parent id's so that the last parent is first in the returned array. So for the above example, if I pass in that object into my function, it should return the id's of the parents like this:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Do you still need the function to do proper TCO?

Comment: Why not just pop the array?

Comment: Well if you have the algorithm for pushing onto the array the normal order, you can just use `array.unshift` instead of `array.push`. Unshift pushes them onto the front.

Comment: In other words, just change this `parents.push(myObject.parent.id);` to `parents.unshift(myObject.parent.id);`

Comment: Yes but unshift is 10x slower: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370620/3743266

Comment: But how big is your list? It might be irrelevant. 10x slower when it takes 0.01 second instead of 0.001s is imperceptible.

Comment: @user3743266 when i first posted my answer, it ws wrong. Ive changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findParents(myObject, parents = []) {
  if (myObject.parent) {
    parents = findParents(myObject.parent, parents);
  }
  parents.push(myObject.id)
  return parents; // [2, 1]
}
```

Comment: this returns [1]

Comment: Thanks, so it was a simple logic error, i couldnt figure it out. Also why do people randomly downvote without any reason? I thought my question was pretty clear